# Generating Digital Elevation Map (DEM) using stereo images

Tags: computer-vision, point-cloud-library, stereo-3d

I have stereo image data (right image and left image ) . I want to create a Digital Elevation Map (DEM) using the stereo data . By DEM I mean that I want to create A 2D image with x axis as Xaxis , y axis as Zaxis(depth )with intensity value of each pixel be the height of the pixel .Basically I want to separate various parts of my image based on their heights .

Even if some one could suggest other way of doing the same , it would be helpful :)

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: Have you tried using OpenCV ? There are functions to compute depth from stereo matches, like [StereoBM](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=sgbm#stereobm) or [StereoSGBM](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=sgbm#stereosgbm).

Comment: It is also absolutely not difficult to program this yourself... You simply find the matches in the corresponding images and from the disparity you can compute z!